# Drupal 6 login redirect to wrong domain

Tags: users

I am trying to migrate a website from d6 to d7, while doing so I made a copy of the site and pointed a domain that I have to that site, its all working great, except when I try to login it posts the form and redirects to the original domain. Its the first time I am working on D6, so I am not sure how to fix this. I would love to clear caches, but I am unable to install the module to do it, so I cleared all tables in the DB that has cache_ prefix and cache table, with no success. Its still redirecting to the original domain the site was copied from. FYI I also made a copy of the db to another name and connected that to the copy site. Hope it makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you any "rule" or "trigger" fire on user login ?

Comment: Have you set the $cookie_domain in your settings.php?

Comment: Okay the answer above was not the correct one in my case, the rule was not the reason for redirecting to the other domain, seems Drupal 6 is quite a bit different from D7 - and I started my Drupal career with D7.

This was the problem: The site domain must be changed in settings.php (base_url)

But I guess a rule would also be able to cause such confusion in certain cases. I have to wait 7 hours before I can post this as an answer.